# Kotlin: How to convert test which uses Thread.sleep to RxJava TestScheduler

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, rx-java, integration-testing, rx-java2

I am writing an instrumental test, it checks if when i cache something into a Rx buffer and after some interval(10 seconds) this Subject insert buffered values to my Room database.

The test is correct when I use Thread.sleep(syncTimeInterval). I want to write this same test using TestScheduler.

Here it is with Thread.sleep version(which pass the test):

```
@Test
fun testMultipleLogs() {
    val loadAllCloudCallBefore = appDatabase.logCloudCallDao().loadAll()
    val loadAllLogNewSessionBefore = appDatabase.logNewSessionDao().loadAll()

    assertEquals(0, loadAllCloudCallBefore.size)
    assertEquals(0, loadAllLogNewSessionBefore.size)


    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .take(20)
            .subscribe { logManager.logNewSession() }

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .take(20)
            .subscribe { logManager.logCloudCall("url", "callgoup") }

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .take(20)
            .subscribe { logManager.logNewSession() }

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .take(20)
            .subscribe { logManager.logCloudCall("url", "callgoup") }

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .take(20)
            .subscribe { logManager.logNewSession() }

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .take(20)
            .subscribe { logManager.logCloudCall("url", "callgoup") }


    Thread.sleep(30000)

    val loadAllCloudCallAfter = appDatabase.logCloudCallDao().loadAll()
    val loadAllLogNewSessionAfter = appDatabase.logNewSessionDao().loadAll()

    assertEquals(60, loadAllCloudCallAfter.size)
    assertEquals(60, loadAllLogNewSessionAfter.size)
}
```

And here, this test not passes, the size after expecting time advanced by TestScheduler is 0(not 60)

```
@Test
fun testMultipleLogs() {
    var testScheduler: TestScheduler = TestScheduler()

    val loadAllCloudCallBefore = appDatabase.logCloudCallDao().loadAll()
    val loadAllLogNewSessionBefore = appDatabase.logNewSessionDao().loadAll()

    assertEquals(0, loadAllCloudCallBefore.size)
    assertEquals(0, loadAllLogNewSessionBefore.size)


    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
            .take(20)
            .subscribe { logManager.logNewSession() }

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
            .take(20)
            .subscribe { logManager.logCloudCall("url", "callgoup") }

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
            .take(20)
            .subscribe { logManager.logNewSession() }

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
            .take(20)
            .subscribe { logManager.logCloudCall("url", "callgoup") }

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
            .take(20)
            .subscribe { logManager.logNewSession() }

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
            .take(20)
            .subscribe { logManager.logCloudCall("url", "callgoup") }


    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(21, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    val loadAllCloudCallAfter = appDatabase.logCloudCallDao().loadAll()
    val loadAllLogNewSessionAfter = appDatabase.logNewSessionDao().loadAll()

    assertEquals(60, loadAllCloudCallAfter.size)
    assertEquals(60, loadAllLogNewSessionAfter.size)
}
```

How can i test this case properly? Is there a way?

**UPDATE**

The functions in LogManager looks like this:

```
  fun logCloudCall(url: String, callGroup: String) {
    val logCloudCall = LogCloudCall(url = url, callGroup = callGroup, date = Converter.GENERAL_DATE_FORMAT.format(Date()))

    Log.v("LogManager", logCloudCall.toString())
    addLog(logCloudCall)
}

   fun logNewSession() {
    val logNewSession =
            LogNewSession(
                    date = Converter.GENERAL_DATE_FORMAT.format(Date()))
    Log.v("LogManager", logNewSession.toString())

    addLog(logNewSession)
}

   fun addLog(logEvent: LogEvent) {
    source.onNext(logEvent)
}
```

And this is the mechanism which i use in my LogManager init:

```
 val source = PublishSubject.create<LogEvent>().toSerialized()

var logRepository: LogRepository

init {
    logRepository = LogRepositoryImpl(context)
    configureSubject()
}


fun configureSubject() {
    source
            .buffer(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe { bufferedData -> proceedValues(bufferedData) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following test passes:

```
@Test
fun foo() {
    val testScheduler = TestScheduler()
    var count = 0

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
          .take(20)
          .subscribe { count++ }

    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(21, SECONDS)

    assert(count == 20)
}
```

That is, your test code looks correct, but the result is not correct. The only unknown here is the `logManager` code. Is there any threading in that class? That may explain why the count is still `0`: you may have a race condition.

---

It's probably due to the `buffer` call. `buffer` internally uses the a computation `Scheduler`:

```
public final Observable<List<T>> buffer(long timespan, TimeUnit unit) {
    return buffer(timespan, unit, Schedulers.computation(), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

This will probably result in the threading issue you're seeing.

Comment: I updated my question, yes there is threading for sure. I am just saving my buffered objects in my DB after some interval of time

Comment: @okset see my modification

Comment: Thanks, but is still don't know how to manage this, i mean i just want to use more convenient way of testing my working code(it works as i tested it with the first approach)

Comment: Pass the scheduler to the `buffer()` operator, and it will work.

Comment: @BobDalgleish In my test method i can't access the buffer, it is hidden implementation, see my test and the separate LogManager methods

Comment: @okset If you cannot access the internals, you will have to either test the pieces you can control, or move any testing of the externals to your integration test suite.